# How to Capture events in Vue 2 / electron with embedded web page

Tags: vuejs2, electron

I have a web application written in Vue 2 , and for the most part we would use it through a browser.

I have one page where I need to communicate between the browser and the desktop devices ( electronic scales and barcode scanner ) - both ways. I have got the events side sorted in the electron app using nod-hid and node-serialport packages.

> My question: How to I communicate between electron and vue web
>   application **Note:** The web application is hosted separately and referenced
>   using http://localserverWebApp:2000, not part of the electron app.

Examples:

- Submit an event from the electron app to the web page , and the web
  page know what to do with that event  (e.g. one way , such as a
  barcode scan sending to the web page )
- Submit an event from the web page to the electron app , and wait to receive a response
  e.g. ( sequence )

  1. A property change or button click on the web page
  2. Electron receives the event
  3. Sends a command to the electronic scales and waits for the response
  4. When the response is received Electron sends the response back to
     the web page

I am fairly new to view , and very new to electron , but I can think of a few of ways that may be possible and just need some direction:

- a) Using Vue on electron and the web app and using the "reactiveness" of the Vue framework.
- b) Using ipc to communicate
- c) Using websocket to communicate

Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: It seems that websockets might be too slow for this sort of thing..

> [quote from the bottom of this page; https://www.scriptol.com/javascript/ipc-vs-websocket.php] While the data is displayed instantly with IPC, there is a noticeable
>   delay with WebSocket.

Some other options I have looked at are uwebsockets which doesn't seem to be properly implemented with electron and also https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote , but I think the web application needs to have electron installed as well ( which is what I am tring to avoid )

Comment: You should look into using [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) super easy, plus is vue and nodejs so you got best of both. To answer your problem you should do websockets, which you can do in vue just fine as normal using [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws). Avoid using webviews  just build an api.

Comment: Thanks so much @LawrenceCherone . I guess I don't really want to use electron in the vue app ( web application )  , I just want to use electron as the "server" for the barcode scanner / electronic scales ,  and the web page  ( which is hosted separately )  - be able to communicate with that using ipc / websockets.  When you say avoid using webviews.. You mean avoid using electron as a container for the website?

Comment: .. And I guess I would use https://github.com/heineiuo/isomorphic-ws  as the communication needs to go both ways? - that is  from the browser to the server ( electron app )